# HttpHandlers x64 problem

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, web-config, 64-bit, httphandler

I developed a .Net 3.5 x64 web application that includes a custom HttpHandler in the config:

```
<add path="*.class1" verb="GET" type="ClassLibrary1.Class1Handler"/>
```

This works when the platform target for ClassLibrary1 is set at x86.
However, when I set this to x64 I get the following error when I run web application starts (it compiles just fine):

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Does this mean that a HttpHandler can be compiled at x86 only?
That doesn't make much sense to me.
Does anyone have an idea of what could be going on?

Edit 1:
The ClassLibrary1 project is just an empty class library project with a single HttpHandler added (which is also empty).

Edit 2:
I am also getting these warning messages when compiling, I am pretty sure they have something to do with this problem:

> Assembly generation -- Referenced assembly 'mscorlib.dll' targets a different processor   HttpTest

Edit 3:
I manually edited the project file to force references to the x64 assemblies, like this:

> <Reference Include="$(Windir)\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\System.dll"/>

This does supress the above warning message, but the problem isn't resolved.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are running this on a x64 web server?

Comment: Yessir, it's running SharePoint ;)

Comment: SharePoint 2007 didn't require x64

Comment: Well, in that case it's running SharePoint 2010 ;)

Comment: Are the handlers compiled for x64?

Comment: The Platform Target should take care of that, no? The handler in this ClassLib1 project is completely empty btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your dependent assemblies is compiled with the flag set to x86 rather than AnyCPU or x64

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for how to use the coreflags.exe to query the assebly in question

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean? Depent assemblies of what? And how/why should I use coreflags.exe?

Comment: What else does ClassLibrary1 depend on ie what other assemblies does it reference - its likely that one of the referenced assemblies is marked as x86 and therefore cannot be loaded into the x64 context - you can use the corflags exe to interrogate the dependent dlls to see what they are marked as x86 or x64 or any

Comment: Thanks. I am currently only referencing System and System.Web and tried to manually add them from the x64 directory. I did notice some warning messages that might very well have something to do with what you're suggesting. See the edits on my first post.

Comment: Ok I tried to manually reference the x64 files by editing the project file, without succes. I added references like these: <Reference Include="$(Windir)\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\System.dll"/>

Comment: are you making any database connections? that would force a load of a database client library you are not directly referencing?

Answer (score 1):

You probably compiled your assembly ClassLibrary1 with the attribute x86. Try to compile it with AnyCPU tag.

Comment: Thanks. While this does fix the issue, it's not the desired sollution. I am developing for SharePoint, which requires to compile for x64.